# Find Canonical equation of a Hyperbola

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Find Canonical equation of a Hyperbola given one focus $(1,3)$ and asymptotes. First asymptote is $x=y$. Second asymptote is $x+y=2$.

Confused with focus.

Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597980/how-to-find-the-equation-of-a-hyperbola-knowing-its-asymptotes-and-one-focus

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Sam_75 Have you verified that the focus lies on angular bisector?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is $$ (y-1)^2 -(x-1)^2=4$$

The intersection of asymptotes is $(1,1)$ which is the center. The hyperbola is passing through $(1,3)$ therefore  we can write the equation $$ (y-1)^2 -(x-1)^2=b$$and solve for $b.$