# Find the equation of the equilateral hyperbola given one of its foci points $(1;1)$ and an asymptote $x+y=0$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

If the asymptote is $y=-x$, then doesn't it mean that the other one is $y=x$?

But does't that also mean that the foci points are $(c_1,0)$, $(c_2,0)$?

But then how is it $(1,1)$?

Comment: No, $y=x$ isn’t necessarily the other asymptote.

Comment: @Tavish is there a way to find the other one using the first one?

Comment: I think you need the other asymptote at least. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2597980/how-to-find-the-equation-of-a-hyperbola-knowing-its-asymptotes-and-one-focus) and its solution.

Comment: I am not sure, Britanica.

Comment: Never heard "Orthogonal hyperbola". Do you mean "equilateral hyperbola"?

Comment: @Raffaele Yes, I thought if the asymptotes are orthogonal I can call the hyperbola orthogonal two. Which is completely wrong. Sorry:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT
The picture shows a rectangular (equilateral) hyperbola, its asymptotes and one of the foci.
In this particular case we see a square with vertices: the focus, its orthogonal projection on one asymptote, the center of the hyperbola and projection of the focus on other asymptote.

[image]

EDIT

This new picture shows the given point $(1,1),$ the asymptote $y+x=0$ and one of convenient hyperbolas.
The second hyperbola corresponds to the green square. Its center is $(1,-1)$ and the second focus is the small red point bellow.

[image]

Comment: I do not think there is a formula. The sketch helps a lot.    
I invite you to delete some of your comments. I did the same :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope the following shifted rectangular hyperbola addresses all questions:

[image]